# mazda mx5 or toyota mr2?

Tags: toyota, mazda

Before anyone downvotes, this is related to maintenance and repair >_>

Im at the point where I can afford either a mazda mx5 or a toyota mr2 (budget of about £2000)

iv'e owned about 5 cars in the last 2 years and all of them have been fairly reliable and only required minimal spending (brake pads, bulbs, etc)

has anyone owned either of the two cars and can point out any common faults or costly fixes that either might incur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the 2, the MR2 is typically more reliable.  It's classic overbuilt Toyota.  However, the parts are obscenely expensive and can take days to weeks to get when you should happen to need one.  Miata parts are cheap and readily available.

I wouldn't make a decision based on that though.  It's not like deciding between econobox A and econobox B.  The MR2 and Miata, other than having 2 seats, really are very different cars...

Answer (score 1):

A good indicator in the decision can be this question - which one is still being manufactured, has a large following and aftermarket part support? What this may imply is that you may have more luck finding cheaper parts for the MX5 than MR2 as well as getting more support on the forums or from local clubs.